# Check Response Time, Length and URL status(get code 200,404 etc ) using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, web, web-crawler

I have multiple URL's for that I want to check the status like URL Status(return code like 200,404 etc). Below is the code that will getcode. I want to check response time, length from the same code. Can anyone help me to modify below code to find response time,length and getcode for multiple urls.

```
import socket
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

import urllib
socket.setdefaulttimeout( 23 )  # timeout in seconds
#print "---------URL----------", " ---Status Code---"
url='https://www.google.com'

    try :
      response = urlopen( url )
    except HTTPError, e:
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request. Reason:', str(e.code)
        #Want to get code for that but its not showing

    except URLError, e:
        print 'We failed to reach a server. Reason:', str(e.reasonse)
        #Want to get code for that but its not showing


    else :

        code=urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()
        **#here getcode is working
        print url,"-------->", code
        #print 'got response!'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your use case is better-suited to the Requests library. Install that with `pip install requests` and check out the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/). You should be up and running in no time!

Answer (score 1):

Following code will print the response status and headers for all successful requests followed by the time it took to complete it:

```
import socket
import time
from urllib2 import urlopen

URLS = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com']
socket.setdefaulttimeout( 23 )  # timeout in seconds

for url in URLS:
    print 'Checking URL {0}'.format(url)
    start = time.clock()
    try:
        response = urlopen(url)
        print response.getcode()
        print response.info()
    except StandardError, e:
        print 'Check failed: {0}'.format(e)

    print 'took {0}s\n'.format(time.clock() - start)
```

Output:

```
Checking URL http://www.google.com
200
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 05:12:30 GMT
Expires: -1
...

took 0.21013614795s

Checking URL http://www.yahoo.com
200
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 05:12:31 GMT
...

took 0.983750700381s
```

As @contracode suggested you might want to take a look at [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) which is the most popular HTTP library for Python.

Comment: requests is looking bit slow . urllib is giving fast response and providing status code bit faster that requests.

Comment: Since you only want to know the status code and some response headers you could use HTTP HEAD instead of GET by calling [`requests.head`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=requests.head#requests.head), it should be even faster.

Comment: Its showing 302 for google.com instead of 200 when using .head. Any specific reason?

Comment: Requests seem to [follow redirects automatically](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) for all other methods but HEAD. This will explain the different status code. You can enable redirection with extra parameter: `requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)` but this will naturally slow it down since it needs to make multiple requests.

Comment: Looks interesting. I am thinking to use both urllib and requests now in code

Comment: To get URL code and error code status , will use urllib and for response time requests. May be it will be good combination.

Comment: As I have to check 500+,URLs so need to be fast . Will use urllib and requests both.